# Where clause in complex linq query giving the following error "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause linq"

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linqpad

I have a tricky linq query that keeps giving trouble when I put a "where" clause in one of its subqueries.

This is the schema I'm working with:

**Car**
Name - (nvarchar)
Garage_Id - (uniqueidentifier) - FK
Id - (uniqueIdentifier) - PK

**Garage**
Id(Uniqueidentifier) - PK
Name(nvarchar)

**CarTire**
Recorded - (datetime) - PK
CarId - (uniqueidentifier) - PK
TireId - (uniqueIdentifier) - PK

**Tire**
SerialNumber - (varchar)
Id - (uniqueidentifier) - PK

**SidewallImpact**
Recorded - (datetime) - PK
TireId - (uniqueidentifier) - PK, FK

**TreadImpact**
Recorded - (datetime) - PK
TireId - (uniqueidentifier) - PL, FK

**CarBodyImpact**
Recorded -(datetime) - PK
CarId - (uniqueidentifier) - PK, FK

This is what I'm trying to achieve with my query(pardon the crappy formatting):

> **Name** ----------- **Id** ----------  **sidewallimpact** --  **treadimpact**  -----**carbodyimpact**
>   Red Car --------12334 ------1 ----------------------22--------------------34

I can get what I want with the following sql query:

```
SELECT TOP(12) cr.NAME, 
           cr.id, 
           t.sidewallimpact, 
           p.treadimpact, 
           s.carbodyimpact, 
           ( t.sidewallimpact
             + p.treadimpact
             + s.carbodyimpact ) Totals 
FROM   car cr 
   JOIN (SELECT th.carId, 
                Count(*) sidewallimpact
         FROM   CarTire th 
                JOIN tires ti 
                  ON th.tireid = ti.id 
                JOIN sidewallimpact tah 
                  ON ti.id = tah.tireid 
         WHERE  ( tah.recorded >= '01/01/2014' 
                  AND tah.recorded <= '09/25/2014' ) 
         GROUP  BY th.carId) t 
     ON cr.id = t.carid 
   JOIN (SELECT th.carid, 
                Count(*) treadimpact
         FROM   CarTire th 
                JOIN tires ti 
                  ON th.tireid = ti.id 
                JOIN treadimpact pah 
                  ON ti.id = pah.tireid 
         WHERE  ( pah.recorded >= '01/01/2014' 
                  AND pah.recorded <= '09/25/2014' ) 
         GROUP  BY th.carid) p 
     ON cr.id = p.carid 
   JOIN (SELECT cr.id, 
                Count(*) carbodyimpact 
         FROM   car cr 
                JOIN carbodyimpact sah 
                  ON cr.id = sah.carid 
         WHERE  ( sah.recorded >= '01/01/2014' 
                  AND sah.recorded <= '09/25/2014' ) 
         GROUP  BY tr.id) s 
     ON cr.id = s.id 
WHERE  cr.garage_id = 'A6087B27-6E18-4B50-B8A6-7E1F746A312E' 
ORDER  BY totals DESC
```

But when I try to translate this to linq using linqpad I run into issues. Here's what I have in linqpad now:

```
Void Main()
{
var top12 = from tr in Cars
where tr.Garage_Id == new Guid("A6087B27-6E18-4B50-B8A6-7E1F746A312E")
    join t in (
        from th in CarTire
        join ti in Tires
        on th.TireId equals ti.Id 
        join tah in SideWallImpact                      
        on ti.Id equals tah.TireId              
        where (th.Recorded >= new DateTime(2014, 01,01) && th.Recorded <= new DateTime(2014,9,25))

        into j1     
        from j2 in j1
        group j2 by th.CarId into grouped       
        select new { CarId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count(t => t != null)}
    ) on tr.Id equals t.CarId
    join p in
    (
    from th in CarTire
        join ti in Tires
        on th.TireId equals ti.Id 
        join pah in TreadImpact                     
        on ti.Id equals pah.TireId              
        where (th.Recorded >= new DateTime(2014, 01,01) && th.Recorded <= new DateTime(2014,9,25))

        into j1     
        from j2 in j1
        group j2 by th.CarId into grouped       
        select new { CarId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count(t => t != null)}
    )
     on tr.Id equals p.CarId
    select new {Name = tr.Name, Id = tr.Id,  SidWallCount = t.Count, TreadCount = p.Count };

    top12.Dump();
}
```

Linq pad chokes on the following line:

```
where (tah.Recorded >= new DateTime(2014, 01,01) && tah.Recorded <= new DateTime(2014,9,25))
```

and gives this error:

```
"A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause linq"
```

I've tried moving that *where* clause everywhere and still get the same error. Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I didn't include the join to the BodyImpact table to keep things relatively short. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno,

move the where clause between the from clause and group by clause

from this

```
where (tah.Recorded >= new DateTime(2014, 01,01) && tah.Recorded <= new DateTime(2014,9,25))
into j1     
from j2 in j1
group j2 by th.CarId into grouped
```

to this

```
into j1     
from j2 in j1
where (th.Recorded >= new DateTime(2014, 01,01) && th.Recorded <= new DateTime(2014,9,25))
group j2 by th.CarId into grouped
```

I think you will need to rename the tah.Recorded to th.Recorded also.

I hope this helps